# c# Make a 2D array, chose the column length and check if all sums of rows are equal

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, 2d, row

This exercise is rather difficult for me, I really appreciate the help.

Exercise:
Read a 2D array and calculate the sum per column. If all sums are equal print Yes otherwise No.

Example:

-input

`2` (Column height)

```
11 11 18 15 2
13 13 1 4 6
```

-output

`False`

My code so far which doesn't store values in the array:

````
            Console.Write("Input column length: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
            int arr_length = arr.GetLength(0);
            int[,] arr1 = new int[n, arr_length];

            Console.Write("\nThe matrix is : \n");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (j = 0; j < arr_length; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", arr1[i, j]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n\n"); ```
````

Comment: How can you tell the number of rows in the text file before you read the file?  It is better to make arr1 a list object so you can add rows :  List<List<int>> arr1.  The once data is in a list you can get the sum.

Comment: What format is the Input?  does it come from a file?  an input string?  or does the array already exist, and you are just reading it?

Comment: `arr.GetLength(0)` will return 9, right? I don't think that's the number you want. Maybe don't work with 9 numbers, where number of rows and number of columns is equal, but maybe with 12 numbers. When you know how "long" a column is (i.e. how many rows it has), you can calculate how many columns there are.

Comment: @jasttim - judging from the example code, it seems obvious that the input comes from the console.

Comment: `int[,] arr1 = new int[arr_length/n, n];` should give you the right array size

Comment: You don't need to create a 2d array to check the sum of columns. :)